# JavaScript If Else with Return

Tags: javascript

Still doing the Codecademy training for JavaScript and I've hit a road block.

Here's the code:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
if (isEven % 2 === 0) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
};

isEven(2);
```

So I'm referencing the variable "isEven." Then, I'm telling it to check the number and cross-check it with the modulo to check the remainder against 2 to find out if it's even. If it is, for example, 2 like in the example it should return a remainder of zero, therefore the if is true and it returns true. But it returns false every time. There's no warning messages in the code but when I hit save and it checks it it gives me this message:

"Oops, try again. Looks like your function returns false when number = 2. Check whether your code inside the if/else statement correctly returns true if the number it receives is even."

Comment: if (isEven % 2 === 0) { .. change isEven to number

Comment: You are trying to do a modulo on a _function reference_ here – which of course makes no sense at all. The parameter you are passing into the function is called `number` …

Comment: Take a second and look at what `isEven` really is defined to be.

Comment: It should be `function isEven(number){ return number % 2 === 0; }`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yeah, every programmer would do that, but that's not what [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) is about (at least not the basic JavaScript courses).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you had the wrong variable name:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    if (number % 2 === 0) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
    
};

isEven(2);
```

Answer (score 4):

you could also do:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    return number % 2 === 0
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function and variable have the same name. Name the function or the variable differently and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need change varible isEven to number, like:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
if (number % 2 === 0) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
};

isEven(2);
```